# WordPress - WooCommerce Registration not working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

On Registration page when I fill the form and submit it, the page only reloads and nothing happens. And when I log in with an existing user, it works perfectly.

Any ideas about what might be causing this behavior?

I am using Woocommerce version 2.2.10 on WordPress 4.1 with HTTPS enabled.

Comment: you have to provide more info than that..

Comment: I changed the theme and I was again able to Register new users.
There is definitely something wrong with the Theme, But what and where?

Answer (score 10):

The theme was broken:
On your host, open the file on the path “yourhost/wp-content/themes/new-commerce/woocommerce/myaccount/form-login.php”

Around line 110, you will find this piece of code:

```
wp_nonce_field( ‘woocommerce-register’, ‘register’ );
```

Change it to:

```
wp_nonce_field( ‘woocommerce-register’ );
```