# WooCommerce Registration not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

When a new user clicks the registration button, it just refreshes and does not create a user in the database. They are also not able to log in. Only old users that were already created were able to log in. I read [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28165103/wordpress-woocommerce-registration-not-working) but could not find the `wp_nonce_field` in the `login.php` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: never delete existing fields from databases. It will break everything.